# How do I place text under an image?

Tags: html

I am trying to create a percentage circle image with text underneath. I am not sure where to place the text so that it goes underneath. Right now it goes to the right side of the image. Thanks!

```
            <div class="col-sm-3 wow fadeInDown text-center">
                <div class="c100 p39 medium orange">
                    <span>39%</span>
                    <div class="slice">
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                        <div class="fill"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="lead"> example placeholder text </p>
```

Comment: You need to know CSS basics for this, using only the HTML markup  would be pretty tough.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply put a p tag that automatically breaks like that :

```
<img id="myImage" src="...">
<p>My percentage</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run your code but the output is:

```
39%

example placeholder text
```

i didn't get what you said...
but if you want to put your text underneath your image 
executing/coding the image first will do, if not 
then use CSS instead. :D

```
 <img src="">
 <p>Example placeholder text</p>
```

Comment: How do I use CSS instead?

Comment: use the HTML <img> tag first before the text if you don't want to use CSS.

but

if you mean you want the text underneath and close to the bottom of the image then...

     .p {
      position: relative;
      down: #px; (# - number from where you want the text to go ex: 5px;)
}

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-sm-3 wow fadeInDown text-center">
                <div class="c100 p39 medium orange">
                    <span>39%</span>
                    <div class="slice">
                        <div class="bar"></div>
                        <div class="fill"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <p class="lead"> example placeholder text </p>
            </div>
```

The reason for why it does that is because you are using bootstrap and putting the text outside the col-sm-3 div which will tell the code to put the next part in the overflowing columns. If you put it inside it will end up under it. See snippet.

Comment: When I put the text inside the col-sm-3 div it displays the first half to the right and the second half underneath.

Comment: can you add a picture of that? and do you have any CSS, that might affect it?

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

CSS:

`.col-sm-3 {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
 }`